# Can you identify the following optimization problem and method?

Tags: r, math, optimization

I have the following problem. I have a dataset containing three variables: Person, Actual Location (AL) and Preferred Location (PL).

```
dat <- data.frame(person_id = 1:100,
                  AL = sample(c("locA", "locB", "locC", "locD", "locE"), 100, replace = T),
                  PL = sample(c("locA", "locB", "locC", "locD", "locE"), 100, replace = T))
```

AL is the location where that specific person is right now. PL is the location where that person wants to go to. The locations are identified as a categorical variable with n classes. AL represents the actual distribution of the locations, all possible locations are occupied. The distribution of PL does not need to match the distribution of AL, as long as the classes of PL are the same as AL.

Now I want to let as many people move to his PL, as possible. When someone moves, his AL becomes available for someone else, who has this location as his PL. If there are no AL's left for someone's PL, the person MUST stay in his AL and therefore his AL will never become available. The end result will be a set of chains of people who have switched locations to their preferences, and a set of people who have stayed in their AL.

Does anyone know the mathematical problem to this? At first I thought it was the Travelling Salesman Problem, but that is not the case here.

Comment: In your data multiple people (rows) are at the same location at the start, how is that possible? How many people can be at any one starting location? How many at the destination? What is the cost?

Comment: Perhaps more suitable for math.stackexchange.com?

Comment: @user2974951 - The locations are unique, but they can be classified in the way that someone has a preference for a certain type of location. People want to go to a certain type of location but they are indifferent to the location within that group.

Comment: To make it more concrete with an example, people post their preference to which country they want to go, but there are many cities within a country that someone can be shipped to and they do not care about the city, only that the country is to their preference? If so, what happens if a country is full and there are no more free cities, where do the rest of the people get shipped to? Is there a ranked list for each person of countries so that you know what their second, third, and so on preferences are? [cnt]

Comment: If preference is just a yes/no kind of variable, how do you choose which person to ship if there are more applications to a country then there are available cities? At random? What is the cost...? What if a person in already at location A (and wants to stay there) and another person wants to get there, but there are no more places, who gets priority? The person who is already at that position?